# Calculated field from 3 other fields T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated field in my stored proc. I have a `projectID` column and 3 columns with a 'yes' or 'no' values in them which correspond to the region impacted. I have to collect all the 'yes' values and insert the name of the corresponding region into a new field called `RegionImpacted`. There might be multiple regions impacted.

Comment: What would you want to insert into that single column when multiple regions are impacted?

Comment: tell us what you have so far... a couple tables and columns would be good.

Comment: The regions are APAC, LATAM and EMEA.. I have to take the column names with a yes into the new field. Its a table called Projects.. it has 4 columns with projectID and these three regions with a yes or no.. I have to make a 4th field with the names of the regions with a yes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested case statements as others have suggested will work but they become very complex very quickly if you need to add additional regions since their complexity increases exponentially.  Consider what they would look like with 6 regions for example before implementing a nested case statement solution.  I prefer a concatenated case statement approach.

```
DECLARE @Region1 CHAR(3)
, @Region2 CHAR(3)
, @Region3 CHAR(3)
, @Result VARCHAR(128)

SET @Region1 = ' NO'
SET @Region2 = ' NO'
SET @Region3 = ' NO'

SELECT  Regions = CASE WHEN ( @Region1 = ' NO'
                                        AND @Region2 = ' NO'
                                        AND @Region3 = ' NO'
                                     ) THEN 'None'
                        ELSE CASE @Region1
                                WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Region1 '
                                ELSE ''
                            END 
                            + CASE @Region2
                                WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Region2 '
                                ELSE ''
                            END 
                            + CASE @Region3
                                WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Region3 '
                                ELSE ''
                            END
                        END
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need the following. You will need to format it to your columns and what you want it to show though.

```
case when [apac]='YES' then 
        case when [latam]='YES' then 
                case when [emea]='YES' then 'A/L/E' 
                else 'A/L' end 
        else 
                case when [emea]='YES' then 'A/E' 
                else 'A' end 
        end 
else 
        case when [latam]='YES' then 
                case when [emea]='YES' then 'L/E' 
                else 'L' end 
        else 
                case when [emea]='YES' then 'E' 
                else 'NONE' end 
        end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

```
declare @T table (ID int, APAC varchar(3), LATAM varchar(3), EMEA varchar(3))

insert into @T values 
(1, 'No',  'No',  'No'),
(2, 'Yes', 'No',  'No'),
(3, 'No',  'Yes', 'Yes'),
(4, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes')

select 
  ID,
  APAC,
  LATAM,
  EMEA,
  coalesce(stuff(
      case when APAC = 'Yes' then ',APAC' else '' end +
      case when LATAM = 'Yes' then ',LATAM' else '' end +
      case when EMEA = 'Yes' then ',EMEA' else '' end,
    1, 1, ''), 'none') as RegionNames
from @T
```

Result

```
ID          APAC LATAM EMEA RegionNames
----------- ---- ----- ---- ----------------
1           No   No    No   none
2           Yes  No    No   APAC
3           No   Yes   Yes  LATAM,EMEA
4           Yes  Yes   Yes  APAC,LATAM,EMEA
```